# Infix to Conversion Using stacks

Tags: stack, infix-notation, postfix-mta

We all know that in C++ , parenthesis is only '(' and not '[' , we can check that by writing  `cout<<(2+3);`it will give me output of 5 but if i write `cout<<[2+3];` or `cout<<{2+3};` it will definitely give error , so now we come to know that '(' is an operator and '[' is not .

My question has 2 parts .

part 1 of my question is that if i want to convert an expression like

***"a+b+[(b+c)+(d+e)*(f+e)]*(g+h)/(a+b)"***  into postfix using stacks , will i push '[' in stack too or i will just store it in string like other operands are stored in string .

Part 2 of my question is that after converting the expression into postfix using stacks i get the answer "**ab+[bc++de+fe+]*gh+*ab+/+** " , is it correct? during the process i didnt pushed '[' into the stack as i was considering it as an operand .

Comment: `so now we come to know that '(' is an operator and '[' is not ` : What do you mean ? Each operator is designed specifically for it's operation

Comment: i think you didnt got my point , i just want to ask that algorithm of infix to postfix conversion using stacks say that when you encounter a parenthesis u push it in the stack ,not what about ' [ ' ?

Answer (score 0):

**Part-1**

You should push `[` into the stack too, it's an operator having same precedence as of `(` and both belongs to same class and does same operation.

You can modify your code so as to consider `[` as `(` and `]` as `)` else you can include these in the operator set too and give them the same precedence as parentheses.

**Part-2**

`ab+[bc++de+fe+]*gh+*ab+/+` : Considering `[` as operand (let's say) this is incorrect as `[(b+c)` should evaluate to `[bc+*` as it would be a multiplication, same goes with `(d+e)(f+e)` which sould be `de+fe+*` just like you've evaluated `(f+e)]` to `fe+]*`.

Comment: Thanks @batMan for clearing my doubts regarding parenthesis , got

Comment: i got " ab+bc+de+fe+*+gh+*ab+/+ " as answer and it is correct . thanks mate stay blessed :)

Comment: @omarkhan: Don't forget to upvote if it helped and Tick if it answered.